# Accessing element array

Tags: c#

Okay, I have made another program to be a bit clearer about my problem. I have an object array containing int arrays and I am trying to print the index[0] from the element neuron one. However, I am getting a null reference exception at the line 'Console.WriteLine(ex.neuron[0])' 
My code is below.

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication5
  {
class Program
{

    static void Main()

    {
        ex ex = new ex();

        int[]neuron1 = new int[5];
        int[]neuron2 = new int[5];
        int[]neuron3 = new int[5];
        int[]neuron4 = new int[5];
        int[]neuron5 = new int[5];



        object[,] array1 = new object[2,2];
        array1[0, 0] = ex.neuron1;
        neuron1[0] = 1;

        array1[0, 1] = neuron2;
        neuron2[1] = 1;

        test(array1);

    }

    static void test(object[,] array1)
    {
           ex ex = new ex();
           Console.WriteLine(ex.neuron1[0]);
           Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

I have a class getting and setting neuron1 here:

```
    static void test(object[,] array1)
    {
           ex ex = new ex();
           Console.WriteLine(ex.neuron1[0]);
           Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

I think that the exception is occurring as I am accessing ex.neuron[0] before it has been defined as containing the value one. So my question is how do I access ex.neuron[0] after is has been set as holding the value one. Thanks.

Comment: is ex a class you made?  you declare ex ex = new ex();  You declare a variable with the same name as the class?

Comment: How implemented `ex` ?

Comment: @Sorceri Yes ex is a class I made and the variable is the same name. Apologies, this was just a short example I made quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `ex` in each function, when you probably just need to pass it along instead. Also, you never set up the `neuron` fields on the instance itself. Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
static void Main()
{
    // define it here
    ex ex = new ex();

    // initialize the neuron fields (although you should probably do this
    // in the constructor for ex
    ex.neuron1 = new int[5];
    ex.neuron2 = new int[5];
    ex.neuron3 = new int[5];
    ex.neuron4 = new int[5];
    ex.neuron5 = new int[5];

    // set some neuron array values
    ex.neuron1[0] = 1;
    ex.neuron2[1] = 1;

    // pass the instance along to test
    test(ex);
}

static void test(ex ex)
{
    // access the array value here
    Console.WriteLine(ex.neuron1[0]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you never set ex.neuron1, replace these lines

```
int[] neuron1 = new int[5];
```

with

```
ex.neuron1 = new int[5];
```